# Rails, rendering to_xml not showing model's fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Song model which I want to display in xml format.

My controller is

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @songs = Song.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml {render :xml =>  @songs.to_xml}
    end
  end
end
```

My results are

```
<songs type="array">
<song type="Song">#<Song:0x00007f8ce441b810></song>
<song type="Song">#<Song:0x00007f8ce441b428></song>
</songs>
```

I would like the fields inside the songs to be shown, like this.

```
<songs type="array">
  <song>
    <filename>take_to_the_sky_loveshadow</filename>
    <id type="integer">19</id>
    <link-to-new-work-license>http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/</link-to-new-work-license>
  ...
```

It looks to me like the Song addresses are showing and I'm not sure why. I have looked at many Stackoverflow questions about formatting for xml, but none seem to have this 'addresses' result.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem in two ways:

1) Add `gem 'activemodel-serializers-xml'` into `Gemfile`. After that `@songs.to_xml` will work as expected (it will serialize all model fields)

2) If you don't want to install this gem, you can do `@songs.map(&:as_json).to_xml`

The first way seems to be a better solution

Comment: I didn't try the gem, but converting to json works. It was a little different result: <objects type="array">
<object>
<id type="integer">1</id>
<new-work-title>BBB</new-work-title>....